# Why is the permutations of 6 objects where 2 are similar and the other 4 are similar is the same as 6c2?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, combinatorics

I'm studying binomial expansion, and to get all the outcomes or arrangements of head appearing twice after throwing a coin 6 times without using a tree diagram, it's written that we can use 6c2 to get the answer.

But I totally don't understand how 6!/2!4! is the same thing as 6c2. I need order to matter, here, I don't want for instance THHTTTT to be the same as THTTTHT. And when I read 6c2 the only thing I can imagine is two empty spaces (_ _) and me trying to make combinations of 6 objects in them.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose two suitable places (for Heads) among six, write H to them, and write T to the other places, you'll obtain a combination. And, there are (6 choose 2) such choices. It's equivalent to permuting HHTTTT because any *different* permutation corresponds to a *choice* of two suitable places for the Heads.

Comment: I still can't get it :(

Comment: Think about 3 tosses, and 1 Head. The situations are HTT, THT and TTH. When you fix a place for H, T's should sit in other available places. in other words, there aren't any two combinations having same places for H. When you fix H, it's finished.

Comment: I still don't understand it, even in permutations problems when I was faced with permutations that had empty spaces like, say, parking 3 identical cars in 7 parking places. I couldn't directly say 7c3, I had to imagine the other 4 empty parking places as ghost cars which are all identical and say 7!/3!•4!  to be able to imagine the situation. I couldn't visualise 7c3

Comment: ${7 \choose 3} = \frac{7!}{3!(7-3)!} = \frac{7!}{3!\cdot 4!}$ by definition.

Comment: Yes I know the rule but I wanted to visualise it, like I do with permutation where I can imagine a tree diagram and for combination I can just imagine a bunch of thick branchs each thick branch contains smaller branches which all have same objects but in different orders, just same objects but moving around and changing seats/places, making n! arrangements. Or imagine a person picking some objects from a box and putting each on a definite number of titles, each object occupying a whole tile.

Comment: But with the example in my question I can neither imagine the tree thingy nor the box thingy, especially that I say 7c3 when I actually have 7 tiles not 3 tiles to fit my objects on. I can only imagine algebra.